# Dropdown from database field in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a drop-down list from a database field `product.color_available` whose data is stored is comma separated form something like `color_available="red,blue,green"` for `product_id=10`

Hope above explanation makes sense. I want to display drop-down and user should be able to pick the color and add it to the cart. I don't want to store my options in a different table passing a foreign key.

Comment: Honestly, the different table is the best way to go. But if you really have to, I'd make a validation before you save the record for the user input.

Comment: Yes, I can do that.But I do not prefer it in different table.Data entry will be an issue. So I want to keep it as simple as possible.Is there anyway to convert the value into array and then display as drop down

Answer (score 0):

To get an array you can do `color_available.split(",")` which will give you an array of all the values separated by the commas. Then, in your view, include a `select_tag` or `f.select` (if you are using a form builder) and pass in the array as your collection.